# Selectively disable specified referenced javascript files on Firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

Is there any way to selectively disable specified javascript files on Firefox/Firebug? Perhaps using another add-on?

I'm facing drag/drop conflicts between several static javascript files and I want to disable them one by one until finding the conflicting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best off commenting them out in the source; by the time you could disable them via Firebug (if you even can), their inline code would already have been run and had its side-effects.

Comment: it's a drupal site, the scripts are included by different modules, so is it not an easy task to disable them by hand...